PyQt6 Pixmap scaling error: Arguments did not match any overloaded call
I've been trying to scale a Pixmap image correctly, however when calling the function I get a TypeError - am I doing something wrong?
It's stating that "size" isn't a valid argument, but also stating it's an argument within the same error call.
Code:
label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.main_window)
image = QtGui.QPixmap(assets.images.icon)

image = image.scaled(
     size = QtCore.QSize(64, 64),
     aspectRatioMode = QtCore.Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio,
     TransformationMode = QtCore.Qt.TransformationMode.SmoothTransformation
)

label.resize(QtCore.QSize(64, 64))
label.setPixmap(image)

Error:
arguments did not match any overloaded call:
scaled(self, size: QSize, aspectRatioMode: Qt.AspectRatioMode = Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, transformMode: Qt.TransformationMode = Qt.FastTransformation): 'size' is not a valid keyword argument


Weird error, but maybe use transformMode instead of TransformationMode, as given in the error message.

@oskar same issue unfortunately; I'll just have to run the code without stating the arguments.

or don't write size= and just leave QtCore.QSize(64, 64), as a non-keyword argument; edit: ok, you found the solution

In PyQt only optional arguments are accepted in keyword form (key=value), not positional ones. This applies to all native Qt class constructors and functions, but not for overrides of subclasses, as they're native Python functions and work as expected. Always check the documentation for argument signature, if arguments are positional, don't use them as named arguments. When in doubt, use help(<class or function>) in the interactive python shell.

Strangely enough, it decided to work once I took away the argument names.
label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.main_window)
image = QtGui.QPixmap(assets.images.icon)

image = image.scaled(
    QtCore.QSize(64, 64),
    QtCore.Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio,
    QtCore.Qt.TransformationMode.SmoothTransformation
)

label.resize(QtCore.QSize(64, 64))
label.setPixmap(image)

